# Get permalink of a post in order to make a custom button

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm using advanced post slider and inside of it I have echoed a new button like this

```
echo  '<a class="dugmeupostu" title="get_the_title($ID)" 
href="<?php get_permalink();?>">Kliknite ovde za detalje</a>';
```

But it doesnt take me to the post, it makes url with localhost/nameofsite/"

The post slider by itself makes title of the post a link and it works. My button doesn't.

Any ideas? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute PHP statements in a string, that is not going to work. Your code should look like this:

```
echo  '<a class="dugmeupostu" title="' . get_the_title($ID) . '" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Kliknite ovde za detalje</a>';
```

or even, nicer formatted using printf:

```
printf('<a class="dugmeupostu" title="%s" href="%s">Kliknite ovde za detalje</a>', get_the_title($ID), get_permalink());
```